# Helmfile - "needs" keyword has no effect

Tags: helmfile

I have been trying to make use of the keyword `needs` (following the [doc](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile#dag-aware-installationdeletion-ordering)) to control the order of installation of the releases.

Here is my helmfile:

```
helmDefaults:
  createNamespace: false
  timeout: 600

helmBinary: /usr/local/bin/helm

releases:
- name: dev-sjs-pg
  chart: ../helm_charts/sjs-pg
- name: dev-sjs
  chart: ../helm_charts/sjs
  needs: ['dev-sjs-pgg']
```

Regarding versions:

- `helmfile version v0.139.9`
- `helm version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.4", GitCommit:"1b5edb69df3d3a08df77c9902dc17af864ff05d1", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.15.11"}`

When I run `helmfile sync` , both releases are installed simultaneously. In particular, there is no error due to my spelling error (`dev-sjs-pgg` instead of `dev-sjs-pg`). It is like `needs` is just not read.

Could you help me understanding what I am doing wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this. When executing `helmfile --log-level=debug sync` I see in the debug log:

processing 2 groups of releases in this order:

```
GROUP RELEASES
1     dev-sjs-pg
2     dev-sjs
```

I also see these are deployed one after another (just a few seconds difference because I am deploying a fast nginx chart):

[image: Kubernetes Dashboard]

Comment: the debug option simply gave me the answer of my internal issue. thank you and sorry !